# Delphi - TVirtualtreeview encapsulation

Tags: delphi, treeview

I need a very fast treeview able to list and scroll hundreds of thousands of items also with nesting of subitems etc. The standard Windows tree view control (wrapped with Delphi's `TTreeView`) is not up to the task. It's too slow.

Now I have checked `TVirtualTreeView` which is as fast as I need, but there is a problem, it does not work at all like the standard treeview but in a completely different way.

I am wondering if some expert using this component can tell me whether it is feasible to encapsulate it in a new component so that it will have properties and methods of a normal treeview but keeping the speed advantage?

If my question is not clear, I will try to elaborate it further.

Comment: It would seem unlikely that this would be feasible. The speed is achieved by way of a paradigm change. That paradigm being the virtual mode. So critical that it even finds its way into the component name. I think you might have to suck it up and re-code.

Comment: Surely you can make your `TNonVirtualTreeView`. It's not that hard. But in code it's quite a long story.

Comment: Hi TLama, that would be helpful to me, as I do not wanto to learn to use the new paradigm, but I hope there would be some encapsulation already on the web to use but I haven't found any, so I thought maybe it's not feasible or it just would compromise speed too much?

Comment: You want the speed, but not the paradigm shift that enables that speed? Do I understand correct?

Comment: Hi David, well that's actually my question, is it possible at all? Yes I need the speed, but I'd like to use the tvirtualtreeview as a normal treeview outside the shell, inside the shell it will use the virtual paradigm

Comment: For nodes you can have an internal collection of objects (or records with methods) which will call the owner's methods to delete themselves, determine previous node etc. But the question is why. Easier for you will be to accept the virtual paradigm. And yes, it might involve the speed, but if you write such wrapper correctly, you won't even notice, or just a little bit.

Comment: It´s possible for sure, but it seems to me that it´s cheaper to learn how to use the component as it is than to build a wrapper around it. In fact, you will have to learn how it works in order to build the wrapper. In order to make things easier with this component, I use to write class helpers for it. I don´t know what version of Delphi you use, but in case it does not support class helpers, you can build a regular class that expose some funcionality and hide the parts you don´t like of `TVirtualTreeView`. I used to do that in Delphi 7.

Comment: @TLama well the thing is I could not figure out the paradigm yet, though I didnt spend much time on it, it seems I am going to need to learn it, as the task for the wrapper seems too much to be done

Comment: @Alexsc the thing is I already have a project that's using a normal treeview and I wanted the transition to be as smooth as possible. I am using Delphi XE2

Comment: I think we'd have to see some code to figure out if it's feasible. We'd have to see what functions you want to wrap.

Comment: @Marcus Adams, I may need most probably only these methods and properties: 

TreeView1.items.AddChild( etc.. );
TreeView1.items.AddChildObject( etc..); 
TreeView1.SortType := stText;
Node_Root.Expand(false);
TreeView1.selected := Node_Root.Item[0];

Comment: @user1238784: ok, I understand how legacy can impose a pressure to be kept as it is! Since you look like being determined on this track, my next question is: do you have experience on component building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solutions for you is:

1. Add a new frame to your project
2. Drop a `VirtualTreeView` on it and align it as `alClient`
3. Add methods and properties in order to make the frame to mimic the `TTreeView` interface
4. Implement those methods and properties to deal with the internal `TVirtualTreeView`
5. Implement `TVirtualTreeView` events to mimic the `TListView` behavior
6. Replace your current `TTreeView` by the new frame

I guess this will get you close to what you want, balancing complexity and functionality.

Comment: That what the asker is asking *how* to do. But the how is missing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: hmmm, I presented *how*, but in a high level of abstraction. Let's wait for the asker to present doubts, if (s)he has any.

Comment: You probably answer the question "is it feasible"? But I expect that what @user really wants is the code to do it. In any case, all you've really said is, "implement an adapter". Which is kind of obvious. More interesting would be a detailed explanation of how to adapt the two paradigms. But far beyond the scope of an SO question. Frankly this should probably be closed.

Comment: This approach is better be based on CCP (Custom Containers/Components Pack) rather than TFrame.  However i'd prefer just making some extra non-visual component being conroller for a given VTV, just like TDataSet controls its TDataSource, while both remain separate objects

Comment: thanks for all that have answered, my question was related more to the feasibility of creating such a shell component/ adapter, rather than using the tvirtualtreeview directly. Maybe I should have mentioned from the start that I needed this because I have already a project that uses a normal treeview and I wanted a smooth migration. I am not sure the way I will go but I think I will either use the TVirtualtreview directly or develop a simple container class with the properties and methods I need and then I will replace it in my project.

Comment: I will pick AlexSC answer because he tried to help more than others. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Arioch'The: I guess the asker wants to reduce the effort of moving from one component to another. The idea of using a `TFrame` is that (s)he will be able to implement methods and properties with the very same name of `TTreeView`, so the code will remain untouched (or close to that). `TFrame` is good for people who does not have experience in component building. I took all this in consideration when I suggested this solution. Anyway, let´s wait for the asker opinion to see if the answer fits the question or not.

Comment: the non-visual component also may have "TTreeView" name.

And for using "black box" component with fixed APi CCP is better than TFrame (which would oubluish VTV and all its internals and would pollute namespace and object inspector)